# Reference on partial wave expansion in the context of QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering

Weinberg is too terse on the subject, does anyone know of good reference on how partial wave expansion is used in QFT, especially in studying resonant structures.

Comment: Have you found any recommendations by now?